# Create a dictionary with repeating values

Tags: python, loops, repeat

I am trying to create unique values of `[1, 2, 3]` in a dictionary so that I can select for those rows belonging to either value as values to the assigned number to reshape into columns.

I have this data as an example:

```
data = {'id': [],
 'players': ['NEUER, Manuel',
  'Bayern München',
  'Bundesliga',
  'OBLAK, Jan',
  'Atlético Madrid',
  'La Liga',
  'KANE, Harry',
  'Tottenham Hotspur',
  'Premier League',
  'RAMOS, Sergio',
  'Paris Saint-Germain',
  'Ligue 1',
  'TER STEGEN, Marc-André',
  'Barcelona',
  'La Liga',
  'VARANE, Raphaël',
  'Real Madrid',
  'La Liga',
  'STERLING, Raheem',
  'Manchester City',
  'Premier League',
  'MANÉ, Sadio',
  'Liverpool',
  'Premier League',
  'MARQUINHOS, Corrêa',
  'Paris Saint-Germain',
  'Ligue 1',
  'FERNANDES, Bruno',
  'Manchester United',
  'Premier League']}
```

This is the code that I have used:

```
p = []
for i in itertools.repeat([1, 2, 3], sum(map(len, data.values()))):
    p+=i
    data['id'].append(p)
```

When I create a pandas dataframe I get:

```
                        id                                 players
0   [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...   NEUER, Manuel
1   [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...   Bayern München
2   [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...   Bundesliga
3   [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...   OBLAK, Jan
4   [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...   Atlético Madrid
... ... ...
115 [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...   Juventus
116 [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...   Serie A
117 [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...   ALEXANDER-ARNOLD, Trent
118 [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...   Liverpool
119 [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...   Premier League
120 rows × 2 columns
```

Expected outcome:

```
    id    players
0   1   NEUER, Manuel
1   2   Bayern München
2   3   Bundesliga
3   1   OBLAK, Jan
4   2   Atlético Madrid
... ... ...
115 2   Juventus
116 3   Serie A
117 1   ALEXANDER-ARNOLD, Trent
118 2   Liverpool
119 3   Premier League
120 rows × 2 columns

#to then get:

players               2                   3
NEUER, Manuel     Bayern München       Bundesliga
OBLAK, Jan        Atlético Madrid        ...
```

Comment: Can you please simplify your question/code to isolate exactly what it is you are having trouble with? It'd be easier to reproduce and answer that way. e.g. maybe just start with the simplified dataframe you're trying to manipulate if that's possible?

Comment: `repeat` returns the `object` (first argument) `times` times (second argument), so you are getting `[1,2,3]` as many times as the `sum` of the `len` of `rt.values()` 
You probably want to use `cycle`, perhaps in combination with `zip`?

Comment: What is the output of `rt.values()`? Is it just the string with the name of the player/team/league?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much clearer now.
You may do this (using your `data`):

```
out1 = {'id': [], 'players': []}
for i in zip(itertools.cycle([1,2,3]), data['players']):
    out1['id'].append(i[0])
    out1['players'].append(i[1])

>>> out1
{'id': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 'players': ['NEUER, Manuel', 'Bayern München', 'Bundesliga', 'OBLAK, Jan', 'Atlético Madrid', 'La Liga', 'KANE, Harry', 'Tottenham Hotspur', 'Premier League', 'RAMOS, Sergio', 'Paris Saint-Germain', 'Ligue 1', 'TER STEGEN, Marc-André', 'Barcelona', 'La Liga', 'VARANE, Raphaël', 'Real Madrid', 'La Liga', 'STERLING, Raheem', 'Manchester City', 'Premier League', 'MANÉ, Sadio', 'Liverpool', 'Premier League', 'MARQUINHOS, Corrêa', 'Paris Saint-Germain', 'Ligue 1', 'FERNANDES, Bruno', 'Manchester United', 'Premier League']}
```

But you can also directly get the second step:

```
out2 = {'player':[], 'team':[], 'league':[]}
for i in zip(cycle([1,2,3]), data['players']):
    if i[0] == 1:
        out2['player'].append(i[1])
    elif i[0] == 2:
        out2['team'].append(i[1])
    elif i[0] == 3:
        out2['league'].append(i[1])

>>> out2
{'player': ['NEUER, Manuel', 'OBLAK, Jan', 'KANE, Harry', 'RAMOS, Sergio', 'TER STEGEN, Marc-André', 'VARANE, Raphaël', 'STERLING, Raheem', 'MANÉ, Sadio', 'MARQUINHOS, Corrêa', 'FERNANDES, Bruno'], 'team': ['Bayern München', 'Atlético Madrid', 'Tottenham Hotspur', 'Paris Saint-Germain', 'Barcelona', 'Real Madrid', 'Manchester City', 'Liverpool', 'Paris Saint-Germain', 'Manchester United'], 'league': ['Bundesliga', 'La Liga', 'Premier League', 'Ligue 1', 'La Liga', 'La Liga', 'Premier League', 'Premier League', 'Ligue 1', 'Premier League']}
```